# Drawing a canvas in a html-table doesn´t work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First of all I got a simple solution that works for me to draw a canvas-element.
The code looks like this in HTML:

```
...
<td align="center" class="TableUnten" id="Gesamtleistung0">
            <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>                
            <script type="text/javascript">
                drawCanvas("myCanvas");
            </script>
</td>
...
```

and here in js:

```
function drawCanvas(canvasname) {
    var cv = document.getElementById(canvasname);
    var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
    //...
```

This works and the canvas will be shown in the table.

But now I want to make the function call in a seperate .js-file. So I thought this could work:

```
function tester() {
    document.getElementById("Gesamtleistung0").innerHTML = drawCanvas("myCanvas");
}
```

The problem is that the variable cv doesn´t contain the name of the canvas-element "mycanvas" but shows "null". Whereas the variable canvasname is declared with "myCanvas".

Do you have any ideas what I can do to call my canvas-drawing-function and then put it into a table?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably using `document.write` in your current `drawCanvas` script.

Comment: No, I´m not using `document.write`. I can´t understand why `canvasname` contains "myCanvas" and `cv` does not? I always get the error-message which says `cv` is declared with null.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the document is not loaded when the drawCanvas is called, so you cannot yet find the canvas by id. Have the job done in a document.onload handler.And i don't get the meaning of assigning the result of drawCanvas to a div content.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have referenced your other javascript drawing file in the head of your page

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="yourDrawingFile.js"></script>

</head>
```

Since you already have created the canvas inside Gesamtleistung0, you should be able to call drawCanvas in that external script directly without having to set any innerHTML.

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){

    ....

    function tester(){

        drawCanvas("myCanvas");

    }

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this exmple I just finished maybe it will help you. look at the bottom of the top post.
[Error drawing a circle on canvas when its in a function,works fine outside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904723/error-drawing-a-circle-on-canvas-when-its-in-a-function-works-fine-outside-funct)