# Error drawing a circle on canvas when its in a function,works fine outside function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found code to draw a circle in w3 schools. it works perfect standalone. when I paste it in my WEB page... I get an Error when I click the button.
Line: 31
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined.
What am I doing wrong? I am struggleing with w3 schools sample code, which is not in a function, then putting it in a function and it no longer works. it can't find the "value"

w3 schools example which works fine.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
</script> 

</body>
```

my WEB page

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var dia = 100;
var x = 180;
var y = 200;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,dia,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
// why when I create a function is it not able to do anything outside a function. 
function Calc()
    {
            var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia").value;  // Line 31
            var circumf =  dia * Pi;
            document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
        // DrawCircle();
        }
</script> 
<form> 
Enter Diamater: <input type="text" name="txtdia" class="textboxclass_small" /><br>
Circumference: <input type="text" name="txtcircumf" />  
<input type="button" value="Circumference" onclick="Calc()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Taking from the responses below, thanks eveyone
============================ here is my final page which works great =======================
This calculates the circumference and draws a circle on a canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Calculate Circumference</h2>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">

    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
 <script>
function DrawCircle (x,y,dia)
    {   
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,dia,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
function Calc()
    {
            var dia1 = document.getElementById("txtdia").value;  
            var circumf =  dia1 * Math.PI;
            document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
        DrawCircle(180,200,dia1);
        }
</script> 
<form> 
    Enter Diamater: <input type="text" id="txtdia" class="textboxclass_small" /><br>
    Circumference: <input type="text" id="txtcircumf" />    
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Calc()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `name="txtdia"` with `id="txtdia"` and `name="txtcircumf"` with `id="txtcircumf"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var circumf =  dia * Pi;
```

This looks like a typo, perhaps you meant `Math.PI`

```
var circumf =  dia * Math.Pi;
```

Further, you're relying on `*` to cast `dia` to a *Number*, you might want to consider [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) if you keep getting unexpected results even after fixing `Math.PI`

---

As mentioned in comments, you will also need to include an *id* attribute on the *Nodes* you wish to access by *id*.

Comment: I changed the <script> to this now.  <script type="text/javascript">
        
  var Pi = 3.14159265;
 
         function Calc()
   {
              var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia").value;  
              var circumf =  dia * Pi;
              document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
    DrawCircle(100,100,dia);
          }

  function DrawCircle(x,y,dia)
   {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(x,y,dia,0,2*Math.PI);

    ctx.stroke();

   }
 
</script>

Comment: Get error on >>>>   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext' 
test2.html, line 29 character 5..... ALSO where do I add code like at the top, this is all scrunched together?

Comment: Paul S. I added your Math.PI. I tried this several times to no avail, but now I understand it has to be spelled exactly correct.

Comment: @R2Builder most programming languages are case sensitive, so try to always use the exact same characters when writing code (This can get visually tricky when you enter environments that accept different character encodings).

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<input type="text" name="txtdia" class="textboxclass_small" />
```

by

```
<input type="text" id="txtdia" class="textboxclass_small" />
```

then getElementById will work.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: SivaRajini I used the ID instead of name, I cannot give two green checks, only one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the name attribute, use document.getElementsByName(name)

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("txtdia");
var dia = x[0];
var circumf =  dia * Pi;
document.getElementsByName("txtcircumf")[0].value = circumf;
```

or as the other answers suggest, just change the name attribute to an id attribute.